# Laravel 5 Eloquent - whereIn on join table

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to create an online directory, where, for example, people can search through the website and find all takeaways that have a specific type. For example:

"Indian",

"Chinese"

etc..

I have 3 tables:

Business

Tags

Business Tags

And my model is as follows:

```
class Business extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'businesses';

    protected $fillable = [
        'business_name', 'postcode'
    ];

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tags');
    }
}
```

The issue is, whenever I come to do the search, and try to do a `whereIn` the issue is that it takes forever to load, in fact, it doesn't even load. For example:

```
$business = Business::whereHas('tags', function($tag) use ($request) {

    if($request->get('terms'))
    {
        $tag->whereIn('tags.name', ['chinese']);
    }

})->get();
```

So my question is this:

I have just over 10k rows of data stored inside the table. This table is split into three "Business", "Tags", "Business Tags". The process above is taking so long to complete, probably because I use the `whereHas('tags')` and `whereIn` therefore, how do I go about using the following syntax:

```
$business = Business::where( function ($business) use ($request) {

     // Search for businesses with a specific tag, passed from request

});
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just wild guessing here, but try to pull the condition outside of the function and don't specify the name of the table:

```
    if($request->get('terms'))
    {
        $business = Business::whereHas('tags', function($tag) use ($request) {
            $tag->whereIn('name', ['chinese']);
        })->get();
    }
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, consider looping all of your tag names and using **orWhere** instead of **whereIn**: `$tag->where('name', 'chinese')->orWhere('name', 'value');`

Comment: I tried to do this, it's taking over 2 minutes to find anything. There are 7-10k records in the database, most, if not all of these have between 1-2 tags  there are 25k tags stored for all of the businesses - Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an index in your SQL relation between a business and a tag?

Comment: Yes. It's all referencing, both tables. Between the tag and the business! Sorry, the link table has over 25k linkages